# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable (mysql-python)

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am coding with mysql-python.

To add a new record into database, I use the following piece of code:

```
# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","admin","majoranalysis" )
# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method 
cursor = db.cursor()    
sql = "INSERT INTO 
# insert a record
jobdetail(title,date_accessed,description,requirement,url) \
    VALUES(%(title)s,%(data_accessed)s,%(description)s,%(requirement)s,%(url)s)"
dt =  ('data analysist',date(2015,4,16),'description','requirement',joblistlink[0])
cursor.execute(sql,dt)
```

The problem is not to declare `str`, but the error occurs likely:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./re-ex.py", line 81, in <module>
dt =  ('data analysist',date(2015,4,16),'description','requirement',joblistlink[0])
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

The sql command to create the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jobdetail` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` varchar(225) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`date_accessed` date NOT NULL,
`description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`requirement` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`url` varchar(225) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Do you know where is the bug?

Comment: If you use values like this for mysql`%(description)` should dt be a dictionarly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use the `%(key)s` as a place holder in your sql str.So that means you should use a `dictionary` to give the data to the sql.

Eg.

give tuple to `%s` like :`print "%s:%s" % ('key', 'val')`

give dict to `%(key)s` like `print '%(k1)s:%(v1)s' % {'k1':'key', 'v1':'val'}`

In case you still dont know how to fix your problem.Change to

```
dt={'title':'data analysist',
    'data_accessed':date(2015,4,16),
    'description':'description',
    'requirement':'requirement',
    'url':joblistlink[0]}
```

Comment: Thanks anyway @amow. But it has not still worked for me, although changing dt to the same to you.

Comment: @Tung I review your code and err msg.I think your problem is happened before the `cursor.execute`.Maybe there is a code mistake before the `dt` declare.Why your sql string declare with multiple lines but use the `"`?Is this your origin code?